# How to set up socket connection URL for production server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sockets

I am deploying to production my MEAN stack app, I have a sockets module for real-time notifications. However, while checking for errors in `www.example.com` i saw this error `POST http://www.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MgkPNGk 404 (Not Found)`

My code works as intended in development when I try to connect to `localhost:4444` which is the port I am using for socket communication with my server.
However, in production, I can't connect my server and my client.
I already tried different ways to achieve this with something like

```
private socket = io(window.location.hostname + ':4444') 
private socket = io('http://www.example.com') 
private socket = io('http://www.example.com:4444')
```

But none of this seems to work. Is there something I am missing? I am sure this is just a syntax mistake but could anyone provide me an example of how to achieve this?

// Client code

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SocketService
{
    private socket = io(window.location.hostname) 
    // private socket = io('http://localhost:4444') <- this works in development and I cant find a solution to do it in production,
    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document,
                private http: HttpClient){
                    console.log(window.location.hostname)
                }
}
```

//Server code

```
var server   = http.createServer(app);
var io       = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var socketHelper = require('./helpers/socketHelper')(io)
server.listen(4444)
```

Comment: did you find any soultion for this